# Accessing constant values in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig, constants

In one of my entity, I created these constants to emulate an "enum":

```
class MyClass {

  // Annotations   

  /**
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   */
  private $status;

  // Status values
  const Created = 10;
  const Refused = 20;
  const Valid   = 30;

  // Getters, setters
}
```

I can access these values using `MyClass::Status`, `MyClass::Created`, `MyClass::Refused`, as if it were an enumeration.

I want to check what the current status of my entities is in my templates.

I have tried, without success:

```
{% if entity.status == entity.Created %}
```

Which does not work as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more elegant solution (as found in the Twig documentation, thanks to Ahmed Siouani) is :

```
{% if entity.status is constant('Created', entity) %}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Created` is not an attribute of your entity,

Try to use,

```
{% if entity.status is constant('path_to_your_bundle\\Entity\\MyClass::Created') %}
```

Comment: Thanks, in fact a more elegant solution (as found in the Twig documentation) gives me :

    {% if entity.status is constant('Created', entity) %}

Comment: I will never do like that. Just add to the entity "getStatus" method

Comment: @bigmax It's what I used to do.

Comment: Thanks @AhmedSiouani ! For more informations check the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/constant.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a [Backed Enum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php), you can access its value like this:

`{% if entity.status.value == 'created' %}`